# Android creating dropdown list of states

Tags: java, android, list, android-dialog

Well, I'm creating app in which the user selects a brazilian state from a list (drop down list, picker, dialog or something like a list), but I'm not sure how to implement it. Is there such thing pre-build or will I have to implement? if so, any ideas of how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Spinner that offers this kind of selectable input and create your Adapter with the items.

Comment: that was really helpful. thanks a lot! I'm a newbie in android.